# How to use <style> in symfony / TextType / 'label'

Tags: php, css, symfony-3.4

I want to change the color of the asterisk `"*"` to red.

```
<?php
...

->add('titreChapitre', TextType::class, [
    'required' => true,
    'label' => 'Titre de la chapitre'.'*',
])

...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending core symfony Form Bootstrap Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798290/extending-core-symfony-form-bootstrap-theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class to label:

```
'label_attr' => ['class' => 'req'],
```

And then with css add content:

```
req:after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
```

Or anyway you want to use style attribute:

```
'label_attr' => ['style' => '.... '],
```